# Not able to connect to EC2 instance after changing the root permission to 7777

Tags: amazon-ec2

I set the permission of the root folder to 7777. From that point, I was not able to connect to it using putty/ssh by making use of the .ppk/.pem file. Previously, I was able to connect. But after this particular action, I am not able to connect.

Can someone tell me how to solve of this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of screw up your linux EC2 and remount it from another instance to fix it.

https://aws.amazon.com/articles/5213606968661598

Why toy with the sticky bit?